# Move UITextField up when keyboard is overlapped

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiscrollview, autolayout

There is a subView presented on top of ViewA. Please find the screen layout below. When keyboard is shown on selecting UITextField even if its not overlapping with UITextField the view is scrolled up.

```
ViewA
  -> UIButton

subView
  -> UIScrollView
        -> UITextField
        -> UITextField


   ViewA
 -----------
|           |
|           |
|  Button   |
|           |
|           |
 -----------

   subView
 --------------
|              |
|              |
|  UITextField |
|  UITextField |
|              |
 --------------
```

I have registered keyboard notification

```
    - (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(keyboardDidShow:)
                                                     name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification
                                                   object:nil];

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(keyboardWillBeHidden:)
                                                     name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
                                                   object:nil];
    }


- (void) keyboardDidShow:(NSNotification *)notification {

            NSDictionary* info = [notification userInfo];
            CGRect kbRect = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];

            UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, kbRect.size.height, 0.0);
            self.scrollViewIb.contentInset = contentInsets;
            self.scrollViewIb.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;

            CGRect aRect = self.viewSelf.frame;
            aRect.size.height -= kbRect.size.height;
            CGRect frame = [self.viewSelf convertRect:self.activeField.frame toView:self.viewSelf.superview];
            if (!CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, frame.origin) ) {
                [self.scrollViewIb scrollRectToVisible:self.activeField.frame animated:YES];
            }
    }

- (void) keyboardWillBeHidden:(NSNotification *)notification {

        self.scrollViewIb.scrollEnabled = true;

        UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
        self.scrollViewIb.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
        [self.scrollViewIb setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:false];

}
```

Comment: Better to use this library
https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding

It will automatically manage your view when keyboard pops up.

Answer (score 5):

There's a minor mistake in the coordinate system conversion:  [convertRect:toView:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622504-convertrect) converts from the coordinate system *of the receiver* to the coordinates of the passed view.

If `self.activeField.frame` is a rectangle in the coordinate system of `self.scrollViewIb` as the code implies, then the conversion should go like this...

```
    CGRect frame = [self.scrollViewIb convertRect:self.activeField.frame toView:self.view];
```

Notice that I also suggest changing `self.viewSelf.superview` to `self.view`.  If this code is running in the view controller that contains all of these subviews, then self.view should be sufficient and correct.

Comment: with the suggested change i am still facing the issue

Comment: Hmm. Sorry to hear. I'll build this myself later today and let you know what I turn up. Can you, in the meantime, log the frames of all the views and post them here?  Button, subview, scrollview and its two textviews ?

Comment: Please find the project https://github.com/dssandeep/ScrollTextField.git

Comment: Hmm.   Can't run it.  I get "invalid argument".  Must be something in the build settings.  Also, super unusual and complex setup.  Are you just trying to have "viewself" (with the two text fields) popup over the main view?  The recommended way to do that is with another view controller.

Comment: There are some more UI elements in viewself.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that you are always scrolling up, no matter if the keyboard overlaps your textfield or not.

You would have to get the frame of the textfield, calculate the distance to the bottom of the screen and check if the keyboard height (plus possible toolbar on top of it) would overlap your textfield and only then scroll up.

Anyways, I personally gave up on implementing scroll up behavior again and again. I now switched to using IQKeyboardManager. Simply install it as a Pod in your project and call `IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager().enable = true` in application(didFinishLaunchingWithOptions) and you are all set.

You even get a toolbar with next/previous and done button for free.

Answer (score 2):

Don't get worry when we are in the world with the lots of open libraries.

Use  [KeyboardLib](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager)  Lib by adding it to code or by the pod.

**Just build it**. On every Keyboard open that will show option for the Next, previous arrow with the Done button.
**Zero line of code** with automatic event handling.

May be this one will solve the issue and a solution for the app betterment.

Answer (score 2):

```
*Add this in your Controller or the other way is to create a category on UITextField. If you are creating a category on UITextfield just call below methods in delegate methods of UITextField. 


            static CGFloat  const  MINIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION = 0.4;
            static CGFloat  const  MAXIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION = 0.8;
            static CGFloat  const  PORTRAIT_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT = 185;
            static CGFloat  const  PORTRAIT_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT1 = 230;
            static CGFloat  const  LANDSCAPE_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT = 140;
            static CGFloat  const  KEYBOARD_ANIMATION_DURATION = 0.3;

    - (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField view:(UIView *)view{

          CGRect textFieldRect = [view.window convertRect:textField.bounds fromView:textField];

          CGRect viewRect = [view.window convertRect:view.bounds fromView:view];CGFloat midline = textFieldRect.origin.y + 0.5 * textFieldRect.size.height;

          CGFloat numerator = midline - viewRect.origin.y - MINIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION * viewRect.size.height;

         CGFloat denominator = (MAXIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION - MINIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION) * viewRect.size.height;

         CGFloat heightFraction = numerator / denominator;
                        if (heightFraction < 0.0)
                        {
                            heightFraction = 0.0;
                        }
                        else if (heightFraction > 1.0)
                        {
                            heightFraction = 1.0;
                        }
                        UIInterfaceOrientation orientation =
                        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
                        if([[ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ].size.height == 568)
                        {
                            if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait ||
                                orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
                            {
                                animatedDistance = floor(PORTRAIT_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT * heightFraction);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                animatedDistance = floor(LANDSCAPE_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT * heightFraction);
                            }
                        }
                        else{
                            if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait ||
                                orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
                            {
                                animatedDistance = floor(PORTRAIT_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT * heightFraction + 23);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                animatedDistance = floor(LANDSCAPE_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT * heightFraction + 23);
                            }
                        }

                        CGRect viewFrame = view.frame;
                        viewFrame.origin.y -= animatedDistance;
                        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
                        [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
                        [UIView setAnimationDuration:KEYBOARD_ANIMATION_DURATION];
                        [view setFrame:viewFrame];
                        [UIView commitAnimations];

}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField view:(UIView *)view 

CGRect viewFrame = view.frame;
         viewFrame.origin.y += animatedDistance;
                        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
                        [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCur rentState:YES];
                        [UIView setAnimationDuration:KEYBOARD_ANIMATION_DURATION];
                        [view setFrame:viewFrame];
                        [UIView commitAnimations];
                    }*
```